# Query Error: Automation failed due to system error

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am seeing this error when trying to run a query in Query Studio attempting to return other products an author has written for a given user with a recent order: "Automation failed due to system error."

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.Id AS UserId,
    u.FirstName AS FirstName,
    STRING_AGG(pr.ProductId, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pr.ProductId DESC) As Recommendations
FROM ent.Account_Salesforce_1 u
JOIN ent.Order_Line__c_Salesforce_1 o ON u.Id = o.UserId__c
JOIN Products p ON o.ProductId__c = p.ProductId
INNER JOIN Products pr ON p.AuthorId = pr.AuthorId
WHERE o.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
AND p.AuthorId IS NOT NULL
AND p.ProductId != pr.ProductId
GROUP BY u.Id,u.FirstName
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on solving this?

Comment: Here are a few general testing tips without knowing the internals:
1. Use sub-queries to build intermediate results before joining.
2. Reduce query complexity. Ask simple questions first.
3. Consider querying smaller data volumes and see if last week's or a day's worth of filter conditions work
4. Contact support and they might provide insights, from the backend logs